# Apply style to ALL elements

Tags: css

One thing I really like doing is defaulting all of my divs to use

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

It makes it very easy to manage element dimensions.  But I want to have this be the default stlye on ALL elements whose display is block and explicitly override this when I need to.  Is there any easy way to do this or do I have to manually specify which elements receive this style?  I know 99% of these issues will be solved with

```
html, body, div{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

but there are still plenty of elements that will need this and I'd rather not forget and discover that my page looks like crap.

Comment: `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` , isn't it? But it's for all, not only those, who are `display: block;`

Comment: Here is a complete list of all selectors, pretty useful. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a general selector:

```
*{box-sizing:border-box;}
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for.  I'm surprised this didn't appear in my initial search.  Will accept when I am able.